googlecredentials threw exception with message : User JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed Json
I am setting the properties in application yaml to establish connection with postgres sql using gcp as given in the screenshot
But I am getting an error googlecredentials threw exception with message : User JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed Json at line 1 column1
Could someone please help me with this

